# Mobilenet SSD input shape

Tags: numpy, deep-learning, object-detection, mobilenet, tensorflow-lite

I have trained a mobile SSD V2 model on a custom dataset for a single object detection task, and I have converted it to tflite. When I load the .tflite model using the interpreter for testing, and geting the input details using : `input_details = model.get_input_details()`, it outputs

```
[{'name': 'normalized_input_image_tensor',
'index': 272,
'shape': array([  1, 300, 300,   3], dtype=int32),
'dtype': numpy.uint8,
'quantization': (0.0078125, 128)}]
```

I understand that the "300x300" are the images height and width, "3" is for the RGB channel, but  to what the first element ("1") is referring ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shape: [Batch_size, height, width, channel]

If you want to change that size, you need to set up it before converting into the pb file, for example using [export_inference_graph](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/7ae6bfdd0be6e2b7da569e7d03b827395ffddae6/research/object_detection/export_inference_graph.py#L117)